# Reading text with apostrophe quote (`) from Oracle database using JDBC causes strange characters to appear

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, utf-8, character-encoding

I have an Oracle table with a column of `Clob` type that is supposed to store large amount of texts. I use Java and JDBC to store and query the data.

Sometimes we get texts that are copy/pasted from Word documents that contain single quote apostrophe (`` ` ``). However when we retrieve it, our application seems to convert the quote to some un-readable strange character. The problem I’m experiencing is similar to what is explained in [this article](http://blog.harpoontech.com/2013/07/strange-characters-in-your-web-apps-it.html).

However we can’t switch our column to blob as a solution. Our database character encoding is **AL32UTF8** and the Java application is using **UTF-8** encoding as well. When I query it using SQL Developer or TOAD, it appears fine to the naked eye, whether the character encoding is **UTF-8** or **CP-1252**. So these tools somehow know to smartly convert this.

However I’m not able to do this in Java. I tried encoding the text to **UTF-8** while writing and reading and the different combinations of it with no effect.

If I dump the text into a file and open in Notepad it looks ok, but if I open in a Unix editor, I can see the mangled characters. If I switch the application’s encoding to **CP-1252**, it will work fine, but I can’t do that as this text gets consumed around different systems and **UTF-8** is the agreed upon encoding between these applications and I can’t change it.

I would like to know what SQL Developer does internally and do the same in my Java application. I’ve been struggling this with for a while and any help would be appreciated.

My application uses the following:

- Oracle 12c
- Java 8
- ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.0.jar

```
public String getContent(){
    String query ="select clob_column from my_table";
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString,   user,password);
    Statement stmt= conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){
    java.sql.Clob clobObject = (java.sql.Clob) rs.getObject(1);
    Reader reader = clobObject.getCharacterStream();
    StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader br = BufferedReader (reader);
    String line;
    while(line = br.readLine()) !=null){
    sb.append(line)
    br.close();
    }
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    conn.close();
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: can you please show the code that reads CLOB?

Comment: A smart quote is a multibyte sequence in UTF-8, present in Windows Latin-1 aka CP1252, but not in ISO Latin-1 aka ISO-8859-1. You have to check how the bytes are stored. With an encoding aware programmer's editor like NotePad++ or JEdit. Or a hex dump. The often optional encoding should be given for conversion between text (in Java always Unicode) and binary data (bytes): `new String, String.getBytes, InputStreamReader, OutputStreamWriter`; the encoding being that of the bytes. **Write test code**

Comment: Here is the pseudo code. Not exact as I couldn't transfer my code to a machine where I have internet access.

Comment: Joop, Thanks. I don't fully understand what you are saying. Are you saying read it as bytes and replace suspicious characters ?